# How to set dialogDefaultMaxWidth in Office UI Fabric React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, office-ui-fabric

The dialog component of Fabric has **dialogDefaultMaxWidth** set to '340px' by default according to its [docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric?example=sd#/components/dialog#Implementation). I want to change it to '640px' but I'm not sure how to do that. The docs are explaining everything using *Typescript* so I'm getting a little confused as I have no knowledge of the language. All I know is *Javascript*.

Comment: I'm confused about this one too. Did you figure it out?

Comment: Not yet brother. :( I just had to resort to using Modal instead of Dialogues.

Comment: I've tried a few things, but the only thing that works for me is to add a class name to the "containerClassName" property in the "modalProps" prop: `modalProps = {{ isBlocking: false, containerClassName: "my-class-name ms-dialogMainOverride" }}`. Then I can set the `max-width` property in the CSS: `.my-class-name { max-width: 640px; }`. Let me know if you figure out the correct way to do this.

Comment: Yeah, that's one of the hacks to do the same. Sure! I'll let you know. :)

Answer (score 0):

[mtl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020494/mtl) is correct, but something has changed in the years since this was originally answered.  Providing the suggested style will get ignored unless you mark it as important:

```
.my-class-name {
   maxWidth: '500px !important'
}
```

Using important will result in this:

[image]

Without out marking it important, you get this:

[image]